Automatic download of JRE
I would like to use install4j to download the JRE when its required. This reduces the size of the setup file drastically. Unfortunately, i can not host any JRE myself, so i thought i can provide something like https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-22-x64-windows-jdk.msi but seems like that does not work, as they have some wierd requirement in naming the jre (platform-arch-...tar.gz or so). IIRC this was once possible, so the installer first downloaded an official .exe or .msi, installed that and when that was done without an error, the installer continued. Is this feature gone?
I am right now evaluating install4j, but for me this is a killer feature. If thats not possible, anyone familiar of an alternative that can do that?

I would recommend using the generated JRE bundles on the "General Settings->JRE bundles" step and bundle it statically. It is very unlikely that a suitable JRE can be found, and in the Java 9+ world modules that are linked into a JRE are not a fixed set.
The pre-created JRE bundles have a special format, so you cannot just use any media file from a JDK provider. Use "Project->Create a JRE bundle" in the install4j JRE to create a bundle from an installed JRE or the bin/createbundle command line tool.

Why do you think that it is unlikely that a suitable JRE can be found? tbh i know not one linux distribution that does not ship a regular jre17. my application is minimalistic (in terms of requirements for the jre) and does not use modules. i know that i can statically bundle it, but i would prefer a dynamic bundle. in that case, seems not possible if i understood that correctly?

It is possible, see the second paragraph. I just advise against it because it only creates problems.
